# nodejs bigtable copy rows using filters like prefix

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

Is it possible in Bigtable/nodejs-bigtable to do something similar to createReadStream but instead of first retrieving the rows just to write them back again I'm looking for a way to do this on the server like a insert into select from in sql

Comment: If you can't bother putting enough info in your question why would anyone bother helping. Please read the StackOverflow guidelines for asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Bigtable does not offer any direct way to run application code on its servers.

Cloud Bigtable's general strategy of running high volume jobs is to suggest runing on [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) with the [Cloud Bigtable HBase connector](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/dataflow-hbase) (although that requires java code).

That said, the specific implementation very much depends on your objectives.  Any additional information about your use case would help.